# Problem of the footer with not fixed height

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the footer, can't find a way to fix it, it should appear in the button of the page

i tried some css, many changes happen but the problem didn't fixed

[image]

```css
 .site-footer {
      padding: 4em 0;
      background: #343a40; }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .site-footer {
          padding: 8em 0; } }
      .site-footer .border-top {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) !important; }
      .site-footer p {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }
      .site-footer h2, .site-footer h3, .site-footer h4, .site-footer h5 {
        color: #fff; }
      .site-footer a {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        text-decoration: underline; }
        .site-footer a:hover {
          color: white; }
      .site-footer ul li {
        margin-bottom: 10px; }
      .site-footer .footer-heading {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #fff; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: inherit;
}

  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container {
      max-width: 540px; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      max-width: 720px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      max-width: 960px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      max-width: 1140px; } }

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px; }
```

[image]

i want it to be in the buttom of the page

css codes from bootstrap.min.css and style.css

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Based on the snippet you shared, I suspect the problem is in the styles of the main page elements, not the footer itself. This might occur if something causes that area with the white background to not take up any space in the document flow, such as `position: absolute` or `fixed`. Seeing more source code would help.

Comment: @TylerMumford Updated, i added more codes and image, please check if it's more helpful now, thanks

Comment: Still need to see more code. As the commentor above mentions, the problem probably comes from something other than the footer. Post more code for the main content.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would look into fixing this with a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) solution.
Without seeing more of your code I am unable to help you directly but I find that this solution handles most cases like yours.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  padding:1em 2em;
  max-width:100%;
  background-color:#ccc;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i updated the question, please check if it's more helpful now